# IntersectionObserver - How to tell IF one of the elements are still in the viewport?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, intersection-observer

I' trying to make a menu that change color when the background has a specific class.
I'm using Intersection Observers, but it doesn't work. Basically i want something like this:
If(ONE of the elements are in view) { add a class to the menu }
If(ALL of the elements out of view) { remove a class to the menu }

Check out this codepen: https://codepen.io/andreas-rasmussen/pen/oNZKJwm

Basically it's suppose to work like this header: https://www.eiffelcph.dk

```
const options = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: "0px 0px 87% 0px", 
  threshold: 0
};

let callback = (entries) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      $(".logo").addClass("white");
    } else {
      $(".logo").removeClass("white");
    }
  });

};
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
document.querySelectorAll(".dark-menu").forEach((darkmenu) => {
  observer.observe(darkmenu);
});
```

Comment: just check for `entries.length` - how many entries are still in view. `if (entries.length) { $(".logo").addClass("white"); } else { $(".logo").removeClass("white"); }`

Comment: @Vitali but the IntersectionObserver callback also gets called when an entry(ies) go out of view so testing the entries length wouldn't give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Vitalii and @A Haworth!!
Yep it didn't really fix it. It's suppose to do something like this:

IF(ONE of the elements that has the class "dark-menu" are in view)
{ do this: add a class to the menu }

IF(ALL of the elements that has the class "dark-menu" are out of view)
{ do this: remove a class to the menu }

Answer (score 0):

We need to remember how many items are in view. You could do this through setting a count but an alternative is to remember which items are in view.

This snippet remembers whether an item is in view by setting/removing the attribute data-isin. If any of the items has data-isin set it sets the logo class to white.

```js
let callback = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.setAttribute('data-isin', '1');
    } else(entry.target.removeAttribute('data-isin'));
  });
  logo.classList.remove('white');
  for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (divs[i].getAttribute('data-isin')) {
      logo.classList.add('white');
      break;
    }
  }
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback);
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.items div');
const logo = document.querySelector('.logo');

divs.forEach(div => {
  observer.observe(div);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: pink;
}

.white {
  background: white;
}

.logo {
  width: 10vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  border-style: solid;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

.items div {
  border-style: solid;
  height: 30vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="items">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div style="height: 200vh; background: cyan; position: relative;">FILLER</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But i can't get it to work. It was only ment to be colored when the div's that has the class "dark-menu" are in view. Fx. '<div class="items">
  <div></div>
  <div class="dark-menu"></div>
 <div class="dark-menu"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="dark-menu"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>'

Comment: So, have you selected just those divs? The snippet in the answer is just an example, you need to change it to what you want and your HTML structure.

Comment: Hi @A Haworth. Thanks, it seems to be going in the right direction! :) But i can't get the intersection area to work like the reference www.eiffelcph.dk. Check out my codepen: https://codepen.io/andreas-rasmussen/pen/oNZKJwm I'm starting to think it's not even possible at all with Intersection Observers?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what you want to happen seems different from the question - the qhestion (I thought!) said if any of the elements was in view then the logo had white class, it wasn't looking to see which color element was under the logo.